# What does "the Gershgorin discs $C_j$ corresponding to the columns of $A$" mean?

Tags: matrices, gershgorin-sets

It says in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem):

> Corollary: The eigenvalues of $A$ must also lie within the Gershgorin
>   discs $C_j$ corresponding to the columns of $A$.

Before that, a Gershgorin disc is defined as.

> $D(a_{ii}, R_i)$ be the closed disc centered at aii with radius $R_i$. Such a disc is called a Gershgorin disc.

A Gershgorin disc is defined for a row, so what does "the Gershgorin discs $C_j$ corresponding to the columns of $A$" mean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the proof of the corollary suggests, consider the transpose matrix $A^T$. The rows of $A^T$ "are" the columns of $A$.

In other words, if
$$R_i=\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}| \qquad R'_j=\sum_{i\ne j}|a_{ij}|$$
and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then
$$\lambda \in \bigcup_i D(a_{ii},R_i)\cap \bigcup_j D(a_{jj},R'_j)$$